# Firebase Analytics event parameters count limit

Tags: firebase-analytics

Is there any way to increase 25 paramers count limit in Firebase Analytics? 25 events params + 25 user properties is not very much for gaming apps. 25e + 50u will be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to increase those limits.

Comment: Does anyone know if there are any plans on letting customers pay to increase this limit?

Comment: You cannot increase these limits by upgrading to the Flame or Blaze pricing plans. The limits are the same for all Firebase projects. 
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9237506

Answer (score 0):

### Collection and configuration limits

Read more here https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9237506

#### But long story short

**You cannot increase these limits by upgrading to the Flame or Blaze pricing plans. The limits are the same for all Firebase projects.**